# How to change slider range on chart load

Tags: anychart

I am working on anychart investment portfolio dashboard
[anychart investment portfolio dashboard](https://github.com/anychart-solutions/investment-portfolio-dashboard) .
[image]
How i can minimize date range of slider for one month only(on chart load) and it should be resizable.

Answer (score 2):

Use [selectRange](https://api.anychart.com/7.12.0/anychart.charts.Stock#selectRange) method:

You can specify given dates: http://playground.anychart.com/api/7.12.0/charts/anychart.charts.Stock.selectRange-plain

Specify some interval from the start or end using [anchors](https://api.anychart.com/7.12.0/anychart.enums.StockRangeAnchor):

http://playground.anychart.com/api/7.12.0/charts/anychart.charts.Stock.selectRange_set_asUnit-plain

Or use preset [range types](https://api.anychart.com/7.12.0/anychart.enums.StockRangeType):

http://playground.anychart.com/api/7.12.0/charts/anychart.charts.Stock.selectRange_set_as_Type-plain

Easy sample showing this for "one month only":

```
chart.selectRange("MTD");
```

Is here: http://jsfiddle.net/97kc1jpw/

As for sample itself, we decided it is a good idea to upgrade it, use the latest version and add the option you describe right in it, along with a new nice range selector, please pull the latest changes from https://github.com/anychart-solutions/investment-portfolio-dashboard

You are interested in this particular line: [Line 313 in dashboard.js](https://github.com/anychart-solutions/investment-portfolio-dashboard/blob/master/src/js/dashboard.js#L313)

Comment: @AnyChartsuppport it works but when the range is grater than an year then only portfolio line is shown, all other lines are not visible ,how can i fix this.